# Google Maps V3 Zoom Settings

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to drag in google maps with a single marker:

```
$('#mapx').gmap({'callback':function(){
    var self=this;
    var scope=latitude+','+longitude;
    self.addMarker({'position':scope, 'bounds':true}).click(function(){
        self.openInfoWindow({'content': 'Hello World'),this);
    });
}});
```

which is working fine although the map appears at the maximum zoom size. I have tried various methods from the documentation to set the zoom but can not get anything to work with this code.

```
$('#mapx').gmap({'option', 'zoom', 7});
```

The above does not seem to work but I think this may be the location of this line in my code.

Comment: You are using some plugin `gmap`, could you specify it? Otherwise it is really hard to say something.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ - there are instructions within the site but they don't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `'bounds':true` from the options passed to addMarker.

Comment: it then does not center to the marker - but this is obviously a good start. I will look into the positioning elements. Thanks

Comment: use the center-option when creating the map. bounds:true will center the map at the markers position and **also** sets the highest zoom-level

Answer (score 0):

Try this:`$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 7);`, there are no curly brackets.

Comment: No this does not have an effect - I've got to admit that the curly braces were not deleted from trying `$('#mapx').gmap({'zoom': 7});`